# NetSuite: Online Case Form creating a case for an existing customer

Tags: netsuite

I have been trying to understand NetSuite Case forms. I want the form to create a case for an EXISTING customer. Currently, all I can get it to do is create a case and a new lead.
How do I get it to link the case to an existing customer?